# Create column that combines two columns by ifelse statementet in SQL

Tags: sql

In SQL I am trying to combine create a column `id_main2` (after a right join) that is equal the value of column `id_main` (coming from a) if not NULL and the value of id (coming from b) if `id_main` is NULL.

Below is the join code followed by the desired output. How can I create this `id_main2` column?

```
SELECT * FROM a 
RIGHT JOIN b on a.id = b.id;

id_main id      boy     id  girl   id_main2
10       1      Alex    1   Alice  10
11       2      Bruce   2   Brunet 11
NULL     NULL   NULL    5   Emma   5
NULL     NULL   NULL    6   Fabia  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `coalesce()`:

```
select a.*, b.*,
       coalesce(a.id_main, b.id)
from b left join
     a
     on a.id = b.id;
```

I strongly prefer `left join` to `right join`, so I rearranged the tables in the `from` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use coalesce()

```
select 
     coalesce(a.id_main, b.id) as id_main2
from a
right join b on a.id = b.id;
```

or case when

```
select 
     case when a.id is not null then a.id
          else b.id end as id_main2
from a
right join b on a.id = b.id;
```